# CSS, link inactive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was trying to make a slider, all good, i finished it, but i saw that the links aren't active, when i hover on them, the cursor is not pointer, if i click on them nothing happens,except the last one.

I remove the css and i saw that the links is ok. So i've tried to find the problem in css.

first:

```
.caption-wrapper{

   position: absolute; 

   text-align: center;

   width: 100%;
}
```

if i remove position: absolute the links are active, but the jquery movment animating doesn't work anymore.

second:

```
ul.slides li{

    position: relative;

    width: 100%;

    float: left;

    margin-right: -100%;

    height: 500px;
}
```

This time, if i remove float:left the links are active again, but the rest is going crazy.

Here http://screencast.com/t/KLpp6DysMZ8l is a part of the html code. there are 5 li's , and only the last li links works. I have no idea why.

I don't know what to do. I worked a lot at this slider. Anybody has this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle that shows the problem? its hard to figure out what's going on from just the CSS code that you gave

Answer (score 1):

I suspect they're layering on top of each other because of they're positioned absolute, try using z-index to order them.  Use a higher z-index on the active link.

Comment: That was the problm, i don't know how to thank you. I've never taught at this thing, beacuse i didn't know what's z-index.

Comment: Please mark his answer as the solution if it was the solution to your problem.